# Android Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT how to register it

Tags: android

```
Activity has leaked IntentReceiver ScreenReceiver that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

in main activity I have

```
 // Register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic
 final IntentFilter intentScreenfilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
 intentScreenfilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
 intentScreenfilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
 screenReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
```

and when application is closed I get this message.

```
ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
```

AND

```
ACTION_SCREEN_ON
```

can not be registered in AndroidManifest but only programatically. What can I do? I don't want to use Service because if service is running all day this is not good for battery. What is the solution? How to use this receivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not register these receiver from android manifest file. Its not at all supporting. The only way to do it is a long running services and register these receiver inside the service. So if you really want to use

```
ACTION_SCREEN_ON
```

AND

```
ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
```

Then you have to use service

Comment: Yes it is bad for performance, running services consumes more battery . Even I was developing the app on the basis of these receiver and checked all the possibility but nothing out is there.

Comment: thank you for help. If this is then only possibility I will take it :D.